# How to include task links in twig node template

Tags: 8, theming

I have created a custom twig node template. It displays the content in the manner that I want but it is not displaying the task buttons. How do I include the display of the task buttons if the user who is viewing the page has the permission to see them?

I have tried Googling for a solution, but haven't found anything. I figure this should be pretty straight forward to do (at least I would hope it is).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/menu-api/providing-module-defined-contextual-links
The manual says:

Contextual links are stored in title_suffix. This variable needs to be printed in the html.twig file, such as in this example from block.links.contextual.yml.

```
<div{{ attributes }}>
  {{ title_suffix }}
  ...
</div>
```